# Axiom class cannot be found

Tags: java, apache-axis

I'm trying to compile a simple SOAP client example shipped with Axis2. However the Java compiler cannot find the imports:

```
import org.apache.axiom.om.OMAbstractFactory;
import org.apache.axiom.om.OMElement;
import org.apache.axiom.om.OMFactory;
import org.apache.axiom.om.OMNamespace;
import org.apache.axis2.AxisFault;
import org.apache.axis2.addressing.EndpointReference;
import org.apache.axis2.client.Options;
import org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient;
```

I have checked my classpath variable is up-to-date on the command line and it includes:

```
C:\axis2-1.6.1\lib
```

I have also checked the lib directory contains the required Axiom jars (it does)

```
axiom-api-1.2.12
axiom-dom-1.2.12
axiom-impl-1.2.12
```

And that these jars match the package I'm importing (they do). How can I still be getting the error:

```
 error: package org.apache.axiom.om does not exist
```

?

Comment: does your classpath contain only the *lib* directory, or all the jarfiles contained in that?

Comment: only the lib directory, but the jar files are in the root of the lib directory, along with the other jar files shipped with Axis2.

Comment: if you put a path terminating with a directory in your classpath, it will only search for class files there; you need to list individual jarfiles, or use wildcard like "C:\axis2-1.6.1\lib\\*;." http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html

Comment: @guido I changed my CLASSPATH to `C:\axis2-1.6.1\lib\*` (using your wildcard suggestion and it worked). To be clear, what I was trying did NOT work: `C:\axis2-1.6.1\lib\` and `C:\axis2-1.6.1\lib\*.jar`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Asix2 User Guide](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/userguide.html#distributions) describes the directory structure and the use of Axis2 tools to prevent the need to set the CLASSPATH environment variable:

> The bin directory includes a number of useful scripts. They include
>   axis2.bat (or axis2.sh), which enables you to easily execute a Java
>   command without having to manually add all the Axis2 jar files to the
>   classpath